# Robolectric - custom view returning null attributes - how to use ShadowTypedArray?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, android-custom-attributes

I am new to Robolectric and I am trying to test the text from a custom button. My custom button is a RelativeLayout composed from a Button and a ProgressBar. 
When I run the application, the text from custom attributes is correctly set to the button. But when I use Robolectric, the text is null.

Searching I have found this: [Robolectric TypedArray getString() returns null or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650466/robolectric-typedarray-getstring-returns-null-or-empty-string) but there is little information about how should I use the ShadowTypedArray.

From Robolectric site they [say](http://robolectric.org/extending/):

 `you would annotate the test in question with @Config(shadows={MyShadowBitmap.class})`

but this does not work for me:

```
@Test
@Config(shadows={ShadowTypedArray.class})
public void testLoginButton_shouldDisplayLoginText() throws Exception {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();

    CustomProgressButton loginButton = (CustomProgressButton ) activity.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    String loginText = loginButton != null ? Strings.toString(loginButton.getText()) : null;
    assertThat(loginText, equalTo(activity.getString(R.string.action_sign_in_short)));
    assertThat(loginText, equalTo("LOG IN"));
}
```

Should I create a ShadowCustomProgressButton or what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I do not think you should declare `ShadowTypedArray.class`, built in types are automatically shadowed. Are you using Robolectric 2.3? I just tried it and my custom attributes are parsed correctly.

Comment: Yes, 2.3. In build.gradle I have:     androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3+'

Comment: I have created a ShadowViewGroup for the CustomProgressButton and still it is not working...The buttons text is null, even if i set it: custom:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"

Comment: Just figured out that this happens for a custom view containing another custom view. For a simple custom view it does not happen.

Comment: I well check it out. Can you post a sample project to make reproducing easier? Also please not that shadows are not working for custom classes, only built-in Android classes.

Comment: sample project: https://github.com/daedamr/RobolectricCustomView. It is a simple project with an activity containing 2 buttons: first one being a custom button containing a custom button and a ProgressBar, and the second button is a simple custom button. You can see the test of text for first button which is a custom button containing another custom button fails, but for the second button, which is a simple custom button passes: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: "Tap me"
     got: ""

 at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:780)